# How to parse a nested dictionary into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a JSON file which each line looks like following :

```
{
   "id": {
      "val": "dkjbskjb",
      "type": "cookie"
   },
   "country": "US",
   "region": "Blank",
   "events": [
      {
         "tap": "Device",
         "c": 98678,
         "ts": 12988685,
         "remove": [
            12,
            13
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How should I parse it in python and save it to data frame with columns:

1. id , value , type , country , region, events?
2. How to create columns from events as its a nested list?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this?  It sounds to me like you need a guide/tutorial, or documentation, not Stack Overflow. It isn’t even clear to me what you mean by _How to create columns from events as it is a nested list_.

Comment: well, I flattened the file and parsed it to create columns even for the list one!! But problem is that , how can I run it for the whole data set. I posted the code

Comment: I still don't understand what is particular about the `events`.

Comment: the  "remove" part of the data  in actual file, has different length in each line .

Comment: Can you share enough data that the format and its quirks become apparent?

Comment: first row of the data look like this :         '{"id":{"val":"a6ca2903cd4332b521c0eca4a50b0a86","type":"cookie"},"country":"US","region":"na","events":[{"tap":"DEVICE","c":4290,"ts":1571758201,"add":[66877490,34922299,22428721,2296544,8852078,24729310,648102]}]}'.

Comment: second row :'{"id":{"val":"2f507de97f71a5bd30dc969288e9ea17","type":"cookie"},"country":"US","region":"na","events":[{"tap":"DEVICE","c":4290,"ts":1571758201,"remove":[69607372,62568694,68190987,68190879,69394501,69394681,69394630,69274496,68190956,69274488,70959343,70798226,62060831,69274390,68190631,58414895,69274525,68190845]}]}'

Comment: In your post please, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten_json(y):
out = {}

def flatten(x, name=''):
    if type(x) is dict:
        for a in x:
            flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
    elif type(x) is list:
        i = 0
        for a in x:
            flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
            i += 1
    else:
        out[name[:-1]] = x

flatten(y)
return out
```

---

### then

```
jsonObj = json.loads(behavior_s3['mess'][0])
flat = flatten_json(jsonObj)
results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
   try:
    row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
  except:
       special_cols.append(item)
       continue
 column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
 column = column.replace('_', '')

 row_idx = int(row_idx)
 value = flat[item]

 results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
   results[item] = flat[item]
```